# Enable and disable click on element

Tags: jquery

After clicking an element, I would like to disable `click()` on that element until the user performs some other task.  I've seen posts where people say to add the disabled attribute to the element, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

I've seen other posts where they recommend unbinding `click()`, but then one has to duplicate the code when re-binding the `click()`. Any suggestions on the best way to do this? Thank you

```
$("#someElement").click(function(){
    //Disable click on #someElement, do some stuff, and show another element
    $('#anotherElement').show();
});

$('#anotherElement').click(function(){
    //Do some stuff and re-enable #someElement
});
```

Comment: You don't need to duplicate any code when rebinding; define the click handler function as non-anonymous and re-bind it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bind` and `unbind`:

```
$("#someElement").click(function(){
  $(this).unbind('click');
  $('#anotherElement').show();
});

$('#anotherElement').click(function(){
  $("#someElement").bind('click');
});
```

Comment: Personally, since these events are being `bind` and `unbind` multiple times, I would add a namespace to the event (e.g. `.bind('click.toggled', function(){ });`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but after #someElement get the bind(), it no longer has the original function tied to the event.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this hasn't been posted yet.

Add a class like `.is-disabled` to the element after it is clicked.
When the other action is completed remove that class from the element.

And define that class as follows (92% browser support as of 1/29/2017, http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events):

```
.is-disabled {
   pointer-events: none;   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just put the code in your click function inside this scope:

```
if (clickable == true)
{
}
```

And when the user isn't allowed to click on it set `clickable` to `false`. When the user is allowed to click again, set `clickable` to `true` again.
Not as professional as Sarfraz's anwser (it wasn't there when I clicked the "Add answer" button, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this probably), but it works and is easy :p